# insert a new document json using http post apache solr

Tags: json, http, post, solr

**What I have**: Apache Solr 5.2.1

**What I want**: add a new document in a specific core defined by me

**example**: address of the solr core -->

`http://IP_ADDRESS:8984/solr/myCustom_core/`

I want to add a document json formed by {"id":"00001","title":"my title"} to the core above directly from the browser's url bar.

**Problem**: 
I'm trying to address this problem in such a way:

```
 http://IP_ADDRESS:8984/solr/myCustom_core/update?wt=json&{add:{"id":"00001","title":"my title"}}&commit=true
```

The response of the browser is:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":88}}
```

However, when I check on the server side the new entry is not added.

Conversely,it is works if I try to add such a document using the submit command provided in the UI of Solr.

Can someone provide me the correct way to build the correct url address?
Thanks

**EDIT**: thanks to MatsLindh I solved my problem using this:

```
http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/solr/myCustom_core/update?stream.body=<add><doc><field name="exampleField">example value</field></doc></add>&commit=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use `stream.body` to send an arbitrary content stream](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Content+Streams) through GET variables instead of using POST (or a regular body).

Be sure to perform appropriate escaping of the content you use in your URL.

You'll also have to perform a commit before the submitted content becomes searchable, either through `commit=true` in the request or by issuing a separate commit request.